# What is the proper syntax to use for the TableSelect_analysis to deselect everything?

Tags: arcpy, table, error-000210

I can use the code:

```
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(dataframe):
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(lyr, "CLEAR_SELECTION")
```

to deselect features in each layer in my map.  However, the above does not deselect tables in my map, or even attempt to.  I have three layers and two tables, the layers deselect fine, but the tables are ignored.  Also, the following code:

```
for tbl in arcpy.mapping.ListTableViews(df):
    arcpy.TableSelect_analysis(tbl, "CLEAR_SELECTION")
```

crashes every time with the error:

```
Error 000210: Cannot create output CLEAR_SELECTION
```

and in addition the online reference table for table select: http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/table-select.htm does not include directions on deselecting from a table.  What is the proper syntax to use for the TableSelect_analysis to deselect everything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the Select Layer by Attribute tool to remove any selection, even with table views.

> This tool works on layers or table views in the table of contents, and
>   also on layers or table views created in models and scripts using the
>   Make Feature Layer or Make Table View tools.

So in your code, use:

```
for tbl in arcpy.mapping.ListTableViews(dataframe):
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(tbl, "CLEAR_SELECTION")
```

Please see the [link](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/select-layer-by-attribute.htm) for more information.

Comment: I edited the question to try to address your answer, but the exact lines of your code are already in my code, and the tables do not deselect.  I am not sure why, after reading the documentation you cite it seems they should be.

Comment: How have you used the ListTableViews function? Does this correctly identify your tables? Have you created Table Views of your table?

Comment: isn't tbl instead of lyr ? try to print tables names to make sure

Comment: Ha! Wow, thats a rookie error! :) code edited

Comment: and you are correct, I was not using ListTableViews(). Thanks.